# SSH connection problem with "Host key verification failed..." error

Tags: ssh

I can connect to another Ubuntu machine in my LAN via SSH. On both of then PC's I installed [openssh-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openssh-server) 
but from another Ubuntu computer I can not connect to my PC via SSH and I got this error:

> Host key verification failed...

Comment: Dó you use host names or IP-addresses?

Comment: Not similar but I got the same error but due to a different problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/494916/managing-multiple-servers-behind-a-firewall-with-ssh-reverse-tunnel

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu-specific issue. Can happen with any `ssh` from the command-line.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

"Host key verification failed" means that the **host** key of the remote host was changed.

SSH stores the host keys of the remote hosts in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You can either edit that text file manually and remove the old key (you can see the line number in the error message), or use

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

From [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen):

> -R hostname
>  Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts .

(which I learned from the answer to
[Is it possible to remove a particular host key from SSH's known_hosts file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20865/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-particular-host-key-from-sshs-known-hosts-file)).

Comment: It can also mean that you simply don't have the host key of the remote host. For example, if I `rm ~/.ssh/*`, then `ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@somewhere`, if nothing else is wrong I will get `Host key verification failed.`  Not important if you're always interactive, but relevant for scripts encountering the same error.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `ssh-keygen -R example.net:7999` yields `Host example.net:7999 not found in known_hosts`.

Comment: I removed `known_hosts` file and ssh again. It worked.

Comment: file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is unreadable

Comment: Works like a charm. Hostname can be the IP address as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 213):

If you are running in certain remote/scripting situations where you lack interactive access to the prompt-to-add-hostkey, work around it like this:

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@something.example.com uptime
```

Warning: Permanently added 'something.example.com,10.11.12.13' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

Comment: +1, this is an ugly solution, but in some cases of automated monitoring processes that work with dymaic ip-connected devices, this is a simple and acceptable solution.

Comment: +1 For example, for Jenkins executions, this is a good solution. Thanks

Comment: @Lobo can't agree more, i am using it for jenkins, which is cool `sh """ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No ec2-user@someIpAddress-e2e sudo service tomcat restart"""`

Comment: Saved my life. I was having trouble with a script that runs as a system service. When I was looking at the logs, my script was printing always this error. When I start ssh inside my script with this option, there is no this error any more.

Comment: I guess the normal way would be to add the `something.example.com` to the known_hosts, see the answer of @robbrennan?

Comment: **This answer is really bad!**  There's absolutely no need to screw up your security like this! You can use `ssh-keyscan` **manually** to get the host key first.  Package the result of this with your remote script and then use `-o GlobalKnownHostsFile=...` to use it automated.  That way, if someone tries to spoof your server, the script won't blindly talk to the attacker!

Comment: Using this just opens yourself up to MITM attacks. This may seem safe for simple status checks for "Jenkins" (and similar) but, especially if you have the permissions to `sudo`, you're possibly giving access to your production server to anyone that can put themselves in the middle of your Jenkins-Production connection.

Comment: From the man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html
`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new user@something.example.com uptime`
Will add a key to the known hosts if not found, otherwise verify the key is correct

Comment: I solved it like this in my automated build:

```mkdir -p ~/.ssh/ && ssh-keyscan example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts```

Then ```ssh``` as usual (it takes ~/.ssh/known_hosts as default path to known_hosts). But don't overwrite current known_hosts, in my case it is always empty.

Comment: @Hovo , please consider adding your comment as its own answer, as that is very useful.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you just need to enter "yes" when ssh confirm you want to continue connecting.

Like below:

```sh
The authenticity of host 'xxx' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is yyy.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ysy/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Then enter your password.

Please pay attention to "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? **yes**". You must enter "yes", not "enter".

Comment: This solved it for me. In Ubuntu the default is yes so I was just hitting Enter in a Mac without reading and getting the error. Thanks!

Comment: lol, this shit happens sometimes =)

Answer (score 16):

Also sometimes there is situation when you are working on serial console, then checking above command in verbose mode `-v` will show you `/dev/tty` does not exist, while it does.

```
ssh -v user@hostname
```

In above case just remove `/dev/tty` and create a symlink of `/dev/ttyS0` to `/dev/tty`.

```
rm /dev/tty
ln -s /dev/ttyS0 /dev/tty
```

As an alternative, add `id_rsa.pub` to the remote location, so password is not prompted and you get login access.

Comment: +1 for advising to use -v parameter; this can help a lot when debugging ssh problems.

Answer (score 14):

you have to put the rsa key of the target host into the source host `/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts` by running this on the target

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa @targethost
```

Comment: Use `ssh-keyscan -t rsa @targethost >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to directly insert it in the known_hosts without having to manually copy it in there. *With this, you do not have to use @MarkHu's `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@something.example.com uptime` anymore.* Not sure, but it is even possible that this barely upvoted answer is the best of all.

Comment: Yup Definitely the better than disabling known hosts.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, this was caused by a udev problem - there was no `/dev/tty` device node.  The solution for me was just:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/tty c 5 0
```

Answer (score 9):

On terminal:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i YourPublicKey.pem user@example.com uptime
```

The following message, or similar, will appear:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'example.com, XX.XXX.XXX.XX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 00:47:37 up 3 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

Then, connect to your EC2 as normal:

```
ssh -i YourPublickey.pem user@example.com
```

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking` should rarely, if ever, be disabled. You're just opening yourself up to possible MITM attacks.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread and I just ran across this answer, I will just add what I did to solve this.

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts" -R HOSTNAME
```

I just looked at the error message that it threw at me and it said to run that command in order to remove it from the list of hosts. After that I did the following:

```
ssh-copy-id HOSTNAME
```

Than I followed the prompts from there until I was able to ssh into the server.

Comment: As this command I am getting as suggestion in ubuntu 12.4.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it simply because the second ubuntu requires connection by key and not password.

I suggest you use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` on your pc, and then it should work properly. It will reset the configuration for openssh and should come back to a default password authentication.

Second possibility is that there's already a key for your other ubuntu in you PC, and that it changed thus being not recognized anymore. In this case, you'll have to edit the file `.ssh/authorized_keys` to remove the problematic line identifying your ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Other than strictly disable host key checking, you can also connect by typing:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=quiet -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username@target_machine_ip_or_domain_name>
```

Comment: Voting up, because this is fast temporary(!) solution to work without providing the key

Answer (score 3):

You should change your key in this way:
From your given error find which host-key changed for
example: Offending ECDSA key in /Users/user-name/.ssh/known_hosts:5
said 5th key changed, so do this:

```
sed -i '5d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Notice: you must be root or have privilege for sudo.

Comment: No, unless you are doing it for someone else, it does not require root nor sudo. You are editing the file in your home directory. Second: for the command to work it requires GNU sed.

Comment: Maybe you right but I tried to ssh from Mac OSX to ubuntu-server and I have to do that. by the way thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Its means your remote host key was changed (May be host password change),

Your terminal suggested to execute this command as root user

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [www.website.net]:4231
```

You have to remove that host name from hosts list on your pc/server. Copy that suggested command and execute as a root user.

```
$ sudo su                                                            // Login as a root user

$ ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [www.website.net]:4231   // Terminal suggested command execute here
Host [www.website.net]:4231 found: line 16 type ECDSA
/root/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /root/.ssh/known_hosts.old

$ exit                                                               // Exist from root user

$ sudo ssh root@www.website.net -p 4231                              // Try again
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the `-v` option to ssh (possibly more than once) it will print all sorts of stuff which may help in identifying the problem. In my case it complained about `/dev/tty` permissions, and `chmod 666 /dev/tty` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution comes from this blog post: [Algorithm negotiation failed for SSH Secure Shell Client](https://linuxcluster.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/algorithm-negotiation-failed-for-ssh-secure-shell-client/)

You need to modify the file as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And then add the following:

```
# Ciphers
Ciphers aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Basically you tried different solutions until you find one which can solve your problem. If the above solutions don't work, please try this one. If this one doesn't work as well, please try others.

Answer (score 1):

Just do "sudo vi /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts" and remove the line, that holds a key for a host you're trying to connect to and reconnect again.

I don't know about your particular situation, but most probably this error came along with a message like this:

```
my_mac:~ oivanche$ sudo ssh pi@192.168.0.45
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:sx1Z4xyGY9venBP6dIHAoBj0VhDOo7TUVCE2xWXpzQk.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:74
ECDSA host key for 192.168.0.45 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

If you'll read the log more carefully you'll see that the key you've got from a host is conflicting with a key you already have - in this case it's on line 74 of known_hosts file (Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:74). 
Remove the line from the known_hosts, save changes and reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

For most of the cases, the error msg returned by the Linux would have told you what to do. For instance in the earlier answer:

```
my_mac:~ oivanche$ sudo ssh pi@192.168.0.45
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:sx1Z4xyGY9venBP6dIHAoBj0VhDOo7TUVCE2xWXpzQk.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:74
ECDSA host key for 192.168.0.45 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

It says that the remote server host key has changed - therefore your previously stored local record DOES NOT MATCH any more. For security reasons the connection is not established.

The simplest solution would be just deleted the line mentioned (line 74) in your local pc in `/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts` by

```
sudo nano /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You would want to deleted the line mentioned ONLY. No easier way just use your keyboard cursor and backspace or delete keys.

Once deletion is done, save it by command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and quit the file by command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Now reconnect to your host via ssh, using something like this:

```
ssh -i /Users/ben/document/key.pem root@192.168.0.45
```

where `/Users/ben/document/key.pem` is your server's key pair you had set to use (can't find it anymore? go to the hosting site to regenerate one) and `192.168.0.45` is your remote server IP you are connecting to.

When prompted with something like `are you sure you want to add the host key permanently to this machine?` type `yes`. Then you have updated your local key for connecting to the remote server for good.

Hope this clarifies and helps.

Answer (score 0):

`pico ~/.ssh/known_hosts`  and delete all lines, after just reconnect and you will get a new key.

Comment: This is a dangerous solution, because you will remove ALL your host keys. The accepted solution, `ssh-keygen -R hostname` is better.

Answer (score 0):

when this is on the screen:
"Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
you need to enter yes, instead of pressing the enter or return key
try this!

Answer (score 0):

Find the .ssh folder for your user.

```
cd /home/<user>/.ssh
```

Eg : If the user is *jenkins*,

```
cd /home/jenkins/.ssh
```

Then open the known_hosts file.

```
vi known_hosts
```

Search your remote server IP address and delete that row.

**save the file and connect!**

Answer (score -1):

```
chmod 666 /dev/tty
```

is yet another tty solution - sometimes, this device file has wrong permissions.