# How do I delete ALL SSH known hosts?

Tags: ssh, vps

How do I delete ALL SSH known hosts?

I've managed many VPSs before and I want to delete these keys.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20865/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-particular-host-key-from-sshs-known-hosts-file ?

Answer (score 15):

First of all you should remember to verify ssh key finger prints when connecting to a remote computer for the first time, to avoid MITM attacks.

Having said that, first making a backup, and then removing all previous ssh known hosts is a matter of doing this on your local computer :

```
cp -av ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts-old
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The known_hosts file will be created again after you completely initiated the first new ssh session.

Comment: Why `cp` then `rm` instead of just `mv`?

Comment: Is not it safer? What if a crash happens during mv command? Will the file be destroyed?

Comment: @Ginnungagap you are right. `mv` is a one-liner and it offers speed and atomicity. On the contrary, a 2-step approach of `cp` and `rm` is a File Overwrite Strategy which gives more control over how overwrites are handled.