# Dolphin on Ubuntu 18.04 blocks SFTP access

Tags: ssh, sftp, dolphin

I am trying to access one of my Ubuntu servers which has recently changed home (IP address, different) via Dophin.  This is not being allowed with the warning

The host key for the server example.com has changed.
This could either mean that DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host and its host key have changed at the same time.
The fingerprint for the key sent by the remote host is:
.........

Please contact your system administrator.

I realize that I will need to get Ubuntu/Dolphin to "forget" the old fingerprint that it has stored for this server.  However, I am unable to establish just how I go about doing this.  On Windows I use putty which simply gives me a friendly warning that the fingerprint has changed and asks for my permission to continue.  Just issuing a warning and blocking access seems a bit OTT.  How do I retrieve access.  I would be most grateful for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/20865/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-particular-host-key-from-sshs-known-hosts-file   (*if you were using terminal you'd get the same 'friendly warning' you see in putty*)

Comment: I got by this by deleting the known_hosts file.  A word of warning - this is a **per user** file so make sure that you are the same user as the one using Dolphin when you do this through the Terminal.  I had initially  sudo -i'd to be the root user and it confused me no end when deleting /root/.ssh/known_hosts had no effect